# Skipping an if statement if the previous thing is met

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have a couple IF statements and am trying to figure out how to have the first If statement execute something and not the second but if the first is not true then execute the second one.

```
if (condition)
{
    do_something;
}

if(condition_2)
{
    do_something_also;
}
```

I want the first if statement to happen but after it executes I want it to skip the second if statement. 
If the first do_something happens I want to skip the second if statement completely.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: if(){} else if(){}

Comment: Use an else statement?

Comment: another solution (depending on how many conditions there actually are) would be to use a `case` statement.

Comment: how would a case statement look? @user2366842

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch

Comment: Sometimes it can make your code a bit more readable.  Usually I'd skip on it if it's anything less than 4 conditions.

Comment: I'll try that. Thanks @user2366842

Comment: Use an else statement.

Comment: have to vote this down for no research effort because 9 of the top 10 results from a quick google search on "c# if statement" explain how to do this

Answer (score 1):

Use else if:

```
if (condition)
{
    do_something;
}
else if(condition_2)
{
    do_something_also;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `if - else if`...

```
if(condition){
   do_something();
} else if (condition2){
   do_something_also();
}
```